# Reference on correlation and linear regression connection

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request

My statement is as follows: if $\mathrm{corr}(X, Y) = \rho$ then we can write down
$$
Y = \alpha + \rho\cdot\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}\cdot X + \varepsilon
$$
where $\alpha$ is just a constant and $\varepsilon$ is random variable satisfying $\Bbb E\varepsilon= 0$, $\sigma_\varepsilon = \sigma_Y\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}$ and $\mathrm{corr}(\varepsilon, X) = 0$.

Now, in case I am wrong please point out where is my mistake. Otherwise please suggest a formal reference, better a book, which covers this statement.

Comment: Given the standard assumptions for OLS, wouldn't the result $\hat\beta=\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_X^2}=\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}$ suffice?

Comment: @sg1234 apparently not. This is a reference request post, since I think definitely some books would cover this topic

Comment: You will have $\mathrm{corr}(\varepsilon, X) = 0$ but there is no reason for this to suggest $X$ and $\varepsilon$ (whether that is the "errors" in the relationship between two random variables or the residuals from an OLS model) are independent except in special cases such as a bivariate normal distribution

Comment: You can specify $\alpha=\mathbb E[Y] - \rho\cdot\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}\cdot \mathbb E[X]$ if this is about random variables or  $\alpha=\bar Y - r\cdot\frac{s_Y}{s_X}\cdot  \bar X$ if this is about OLS regression

Comment: @Henry independence was mentioned nowhere

Comment: @Ilya - indeed not, though independence is a common assumption for a linear model and may be what your colleague is thinking about.  If you want to make progress in the discussion, it might be worth constructing an example where the actual relationship is clearly non-linear and then show that your result still applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The properties of the residuals that you are referring to are stated page 97 (equations 3.8.8 and 3.8.9) of the following book: **Marek Fisz. Probability theory and mathematical statistics. Third Edition (1980).**

---

Let us prove that this holds with $\alpha = \mu_Y - \rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X} \mu_X$. Define $\varepsilon$ as the difference.

Since expectation is linear (and does not require independence of the variables or whatever), you have
$$
\mathbb{E} \varepsilon = \mathbb{E} Y - \alpha - \rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X} \mathbb{E} X  = 0.
$$
By definition,
$$
\begin{split}
\sigma_\varepsilon^2 & = \mathbb{E} \varepsilon^2
= \mathbb{E} \left(  Y - \alpha - \rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X} X \right)^2
= \sigma_Y^2 \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{ Y - \mu_Y }{\sigma_Y} - \rho \frac{X-\mu_X}{\sigma_X} \right)^2 \\
& = \sigma_Y^2 \left(1 + \rho^2 - 2 \rho^2 \right) = \sigma_Y^2 (1-\rho^2).
\end{split}
$$
And eventually,
$$
\mathrm{corr}(\varepsilon,X) = \mathbb{E}(\varepsilon(X-\mu_X))=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y-\mu_Y - \frac{\rho\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(X-\mu_X)\right)(X-\mu_X)\right]
= \rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y - \rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X} \sigma_X^2 = 0.
$$

So all the properties that you claim just follow from the definitions and the linearity of the expectation (which, again, does not require any assumption on the variables).

Comment: thanks, I can do this myself :) I need a reference though

Comment: Sorry, I should have paid more attention to your requirement! Seems tough to disagree with such 0-tooling properties. I will look if I find.

Comment: I have added an (old) book with the 3 properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps